# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. - Error

Tags: mysql, sql

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```
Insert Into
Developer(DevID,UserName,DevPassword,Email,Country,ZipCode,CellPhone,LastLogin)
Values
    ('Dev123456A', 'Paul Wilson Diu', 'P@ulWilson', 'Paul_Wilson@yahoo.com',
     'Philippines', '12345', '0277824893', '10-04-2013'),
```

Im trying to insert a date in LastLogin and i get this error.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you need to format the date like this:

```
Insert Into Developer (DevID,UserName,DevPassword,
    Email,Country,ZipCode,CellPhone,LastLogin) 
Values ('Dev123456A','Paul Wilson Diu','P@ulWilson',
    'Paul_Wilson@yahoo.com','Philippines',
    '12345','0277824893','2013-10-04');
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4215c/1)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Comment: i change the format like you suggested but still got the same error

Comment: @user2449983 -- what data type is your lastlogin field?  This should work -- did you see the fiddle?

Comment: i got it working in the end.. i used this (Convert(DateTime,'20130410'))

Comment: @user2449983 -- glad you got it working.  See Gordon's answer for another approach.  Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can be explicit about date formats when you use the `select` version of `insert`:

```
Into Developer (DevID, UserName, DevPassword, Email, Country, ZipCode, CellPhone, LastLogin) 
    select 'Dev123456A', 'Paul Wilson Diu', 'P@ulWilson',
           'Paul_Wilson@yahoo.com', 'Philippines',
           '12345', '0277824893', str_to_date('10-04-2013', '%d-%m-%Y');
```